# The "similar questions" list on a Deleted Duplicate Question's 404 page should include the possible duplicate(s) questions it was closed with

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

Take this deleted and previously closed as duplicate question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341502/how-to-tell-if-you-are-running-in-the-debugger-in-vs?rq=1

While users < 10k see a 404 with some suggestions:

[image: 404 suggestions]

These suggestions do not even include the link that users > 10k see on the deleted page, the more accurate suggestion of the "Possible Duplicate":

[image: delete page]

I think where duplicates have been suggested, they should be on the top of the list at least, if not actually be the only entries in the list.

Comment: Google will updates its index in time, and the deleted post will no longer show up in search results.

Comment: Wouldn't it still update the index if a permanently moved redirect was in place?

Comment: I think the issue with this suggestion is that 1) ending up on a different page is a little non-intuitive and posts can 2) be closed as duplicates of multiple targets and 3) be undeleted - so you couldn't really use a perm redirect and browsers tend to cache redirects anyway - which might take it off the radar even when undeleted etc...

Comment: @Servy I have added more on this. It basically came about because I linked to that Q in SO itself. So that removes google from the equation.

Comment: @JonClements could the 404 page at least show the duplicate link that I as a higher rep user can see?

Comment: @weston If you have a direct link then all the more reason to want to see the actual question, and not get silently redirected without knowing it.

Comment: I don't want redirection, I'm talking about users with low or not logged in who otherwise get 404 messages

Comment: @weston If someone's stored a direct link to a question then there's a good chance they want to *see that specific question*.  For example, if someone is trying to link to the question on meta to protest its deletion you wouldn't want everyone silently redirected to the duplicate.

Comment: @Servy Fine, like I said to JonC, should users not at least see something useful on that 404 page, like a link to the duplicate. So not a silent redirection.

Comment: The problem is you then have the issue of search engines and < 10k rep people seeing one thing and others something else... that's not going to end well...

Comment: @JonClements Don't we have that now?

Comment: There's different response codes (no different than authorised/non-authorised in a way) - but not replies with different *content*

Comment: @JonClements I kind of see, so it's bad practice to have 404 pages with content?

Comment: @weston err yeah: "We couldn't find your page - but here's some something you weren't looking for instead!" :)

Comment: I mean, I suppose it's possible to offer a suggestion of alternate pages which are the links to the dupes but then not sure how that'd fit in the SEO POV

Comment: @JonClements I (we maybe) really out to have looked at the 404 page. It does already suggest other questions! but none of them are the duplicate(s), so my suggestion still stands

Comment: @weston okay... then yeah... I'd go +1 for including the duplicate(s) as priority link(s) before the keyword related ones :)

Comment: I've reworded to remove the redirection suggestion and google points. It's now just add those links to that existing list.

Comment: The current suggestion (after all those edits from the above comments) is a good one.

Comment: Isn't this exactly why deleting duplicate questions is usually discouraged? Why was this question even deleted in the first place anyway? It seems like an excellent [signpost](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) to me, especially given how popular it is and how highly ranked it seems to be on Google.